# issue with json parsing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have faced an issue while parsing the json array in jQuery.

my json array is

```
({resultCount:1, results:[{wrapperType:"track", kind:"song", artistId:255303209, collectionId:536282724, trackId:536282832, artistName:"Flo Rida", collectionName:"Wild Ones (Deluxe Version)", trackName:"I Cry", collectionCensoredName:"Wild Ones (Deluxe Version)", trackCensoredName:"I Cry", artistViewUrl:"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/flo-rida/id255303209?uo=4", collectionViewUrl:"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/i-cry/id536282724?i=536282832&uo=4", trackViewUrl:"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/i-cry/id536282724?i=536282832&uo=4", previewUrl:"http://a1278.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/073/Music/09/3d/27/mzm.wwzzwbfq.aac.p.m4a", artworkUrl30:"http://a1395.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/112/Music/v4/25/03/bb/2503bb1c-fbf4-4f5d-b249-9a2c3cfe24d6/075679960399.30x30-50.jpg", artworkUrl60:"http://a1459.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/112/Music/v4/25/03/bb/2503bb1c-fbf4-4f5d-b249-9a2c3cfe24d6/075679960399.60x60-50.jpg", artworkUrl100:"http://a1796.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/112/Music/v4/25/03/bb/2503bb1c-fbf4-4f5d-b249-9a2c3cfe24d6/075679960399.100x100-75.jpg", collectionPrice:7.99, trackPrice:1.29, releaseDate:"2012-06-22T07:00:00Z", collectionExplicitness:"notExplicit", trackExplicitness:"notExplicit", discCount:1, discNumber:1, trackCount:10, trackNumber:8, trackTimeMillis:223800, country:"USA", currency:"USD", primaryGenreName:"Hip Hop/Rap"}]})
```

In this array i have to get artworkUrl30,trackName.
How to do this ?
when i try to parse this i got this error
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name

**Edit**
I am calling this as itunes call back like

```
function GetDetailsFromitunes(data){

    var mvar = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log( mvar.resultCount);

    }
```

I am working based on this document

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to retrieve this as well as how you try to parse it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills thks for reply its a itune call back function any help ?

Comment: When do you actually call `GetDetailsFromitunes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=536282832";
    $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(data) {
        console.log(data.results[0].artworkUrl30, data.results[0].trackName);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message couldn't be clearer. You have to quote your property names:

```
{ "resultCount":1, "results": [{"wrapperType":"track"}, {"Keep": "going"}] }
```

The way you have it now, while being valid JavaScript, [is invalid JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: thanks for quick reply ,but i got this return array from itunes <script src="https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=536282832/> method

Comment: @JobinJose - The [JSON I'm getting](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=536282832) is properly quoted. Lose that trailing `/>`

Comment: <script src="https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=536282832&callback=GetDetailsFromitunes"/></script> actually when i fire the url in browser it shows with "" but when use it with call back function i got this issue, i tried with jQuery.parseJSON is that right ?

Comment: How are you getting the JSON? You should be using JSONP, by calling [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: I didn't get when i call it as an ajax or getJson any hope?